# why .isotope function has to be called when the div tab is visible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, jquery-isotope

I'm using `isotope` to align a set of `divs` that are placed into a bootstrap tab. The tab is filled dynamically through a `backbone` `view`.

Here is the code before the view fills the tab:

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="program">
  </div>
```

no divs to align then. After the view has filled the tab, the element will be something like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="program">
    <div class="badge">
      aleatory content here
    </div>
    <div class="badge">
      aleatory content here
    </div>
    <div class="badge">
      aleatory content here
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

the tab will be rendered, but another tab will be visible by default. So, to view the content of `#program` I will have to click on the proper `tab` that opens my `div#program`.

So, if I run this piece of code after rendering the `div#program`:

```
this.$('#program div.muse-events').isotope({
      itemSelector  : 'div.badge'
      ,layoutMode   : 'fitRows'
});
```

what I get is an *EMPTY TAB*. I personally think it's because some reference is missing and `isotope` only removes the elements in the `div#program` without handling the `div#badge`.

If I want to get what I want, I have to call the piece of code above only when the tab is clicked (and hence the `div#program` is showed and not hidden).

So, two questions:

1. why is that? Is maybe the tab removed from the DOM until someone explicitly requests it?
2. What's the best practice in this case? Is calling that command ok when I click the proper tab? Could I run it in some way when I call my `View.render`? It could be semantically much more correct

Thanks

Comment: Does isotope need to know the sizes or positions of things? Sounds like it probably does. That information usually won't be available until the `<div>` in question has been displayed so perhaps isotope is getting a bunch of zeros and leaving everything with zero dimensions. Use your DOM inspector to see if the `.badge` elements are there, what their dimensions are, and what their positions are.

Comment: you were right: the width is well defined (thanks to the `.span4`), but the `height` is set to `auto` as long as you open the tab. I'm wondering if there is a workaround to make it temporarily visible so as to call `isotope` properly.

Comment: I've had similar issues with a Google Map inside a tab (difference tab library but the same underlying problem). I used jQuery's [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a function to the tabs so that the map would be attached the first time the tab was opened. A `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)` hack might also be an option.

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem with GMap inside a Modal and I fixed it by putting a new item in the `events hash`:

`el: "#modalElemID"` 
`events: { 
   ...
    "shown": "_modalShownFunc"}`
but in this case I didn't hace a separate view for the tab (it could have been a solution though!). About your `one` solution: that event could not be fired and in case of single page application we could face some memory leak issues, right? I would put that in the `events` hash so that I can deference it easily. What do you think?

Comment: In this case I've added in my `events` View hash this row:
`"click li.tab-with-badges" : "_funcWithIsotopeToCall"`. With a boolean you can perform this just once

Comment: There's also [`_.once`](http://underscorejs.org/#once) so you can 'click whatever': _(function() { ... }).once()` or [`Events#once`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-once) if that sort of set up makes more sense than going through the view's `events`.